# How do I remove "permission denied" printout statements from the find program?

Tags: find

Code

```
find / -name netcdf
```

Output

```
find: `/root/.dbus': Permission denied
find: `/root/.gconf': Permission denied
find: `/root/.gconfd': Permission denied
find: `/root/.gnome': Permission denied
find: `/root/.gnome2': Permission denied
find: `/root/.gnome2_private': Permission denied
```

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/290791/16920

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Those messages are sent to stderr, and pretty much only those messages are generally seen on that output stream.  You can close it or redirect it on the command-line.

```
$ find / -name netcdf 2>&-
```

or

```
$ find / -name netcdf 2>/dev/null
```

Also, if you are going to search the root directory (/), then it is often good to nice the process so find doesn't consume all the resources.

```
$ nice find / -name netcdf 2>&-
```

This decreases the priority of the process allowing other processes more time on the CPU.  Of course if nothing else is using the CPU, it doesn't do anything. :)  To be technical, the NI value (seen from `ps -l`) increase the PRI value.  Lower PRI values have a higher priority.  Compare `ps -l` with `nice ps -l`.

Comment: I do not like throwing out warnings. It is much better to handle them. Also, no escaping here in the field.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 WEll... if you can't see program output because yours screen is full of error crap.. which this is the case...

Answer (score 32):

I would just like point out this answer by @Gilles in [Exclude paths that make find complain about permissions - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87634/exclude-paths-that-make-find-complain-about-permissions/87850#87850); it basically involves a construct for `find` that makes it not descend unreadable directories, and in that sense, is probably also a bit faster.

This would seem to work for me:

> With GNU `find` or any other `find` that supports the `-readable` and `-executable` predicates:

```bash
find / -type d ! \( -readable -executable \) -prune -o -type f -name netcdf -print
```

or also this:

```bash
find / -type d ! -perm -g+r,u+r,o+r -prune -o -type f -name 'netcdf' -print
```

For some reason, I need to add all of the `g+r,u+r,o+r` (shortcut for that is `a+r`), otherwise if one of them is left out, I may still get "Permission Denied" hits.

Here is a breakdown of how I see this (note the `-a` (and) operator in `find` is [implicit between two predicates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71221/how-to-use-find-to-remove-py-and-pyc-files-at-once/71222#71222)):

```bash
find /         # find starting from path /
  -type d        # match type is directory
  ! -perm -a+r   # (and) match not permissions of `r`ead present 
  -prune         # ignore what matched above and do not descend into it
  -o             # or (whatever didn't match above)
  -type f        # match type is file
  -name 'netcdf' # (and) match name is 'netcdf'
  -print         # print what matched above
```

Note that without the last `-print`, I get some extra items shown (that have nothing to do with `-name 'netcdf'`); the `-print` ensures that only the name matches are printed (if any).

Comment: If `find(1)` can't descend into a directory, it won't. So checking beforehand if it can or not will just add work (check twice), and thus slow it down.

Comment: @vonbrand it's necessary if you rely on `find`'s exit status, because these permission errors make `find` exit with non-zero status

Comment: I cannot get your proposal work. I get no output when expected output is full. http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/290791/16920 However, I think otherwise I think your method is the best way to go.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was so hard to find this answer, I now wish I could do more than just upvote it.

Comment: Note that the `-readable` way and the `-perm` way are not equivalent.

Answer (score 13):

Use `locate(1)` instead:

```
$ locate netcdf
```

It will only show you files your user can see.

Comment: This assumes that `updatedb` is running regularly.  That is not the case on all Linux systems.

Comment: If locate(1) is installed, its database *should* be updated periodically. If that isn't happening, I'd class that a misconfiguration rather than a fault of locate(1). Additionally, it only takes a few minutes to run it by hand in the rare cases where you're looking for a file that was added since the last DB update. I find myself doing that maybe half a dozen times per year, an overhead easily paid for from the speed advantage of locate(1) over find(1).