# Files greater than 1 GB and older than 6 months

Tags: shell-script, command-line, files, find

I want to find files which are greater than 1 GB and older than 6 months in entire server. How to write a command for this?

Answer (score 68):

Use `find`:

```
find /path -mtime +180 -size +1G
```

`-mtime` means search for modification times that are greater than 180 days (+180). And the `-size` parameter searches for files greater than 1GB.

Comment: Note that in the `find` implementations where that `G` suffix is supported, it means GiB (1073741824 bytes), not GB (1000000000). Portably, you'd use `find /path -mtime +180 -size +1073741824c`

Comment: if you want to avoid seeing errors between the list of files like these:
`find: a.txt :Permission denied`
I suggest adding this 
`2>/dev/null` inspired from this comment:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42841/how-to-skip-permission-denied-errors-when-running-find-in-linux#comment58845_42842

Comment: You can also pipe the results into `xargs ls -lhS` to sort them by size:   
                  
`find /path  -mtime +180 -size +1G | xargs ls -lhS`

Comment: @user553965 Your command won't work. What is actually needed to sort by size is: `find / -size +1G -mtime +180 -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 ls -lhS`. Newbies note: The redirection of `2>/dev/null` just gets rid of the `permission denied` errors which will inevitably appear when searching from root. To sort by last modified date use `ls -lht` instead and adding `r` to the `ls` commands, e.g. `ls -lhSr`, will reverse the results (smallest to largest / oldest to newest).

Comment: How do you also make it print out the human-readable size of each thing found?

Comment: @GabrielStaples: Good question, you should [ask](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) it.

Comment: @chaos, here is my question: [Find files greater than x kB/MB/GB in size, and also show their size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/666685/find-files-greater-than-x-kb-mb-gb-in-size-and-also-show-their-size)

Answer (score 12):

`find / -size +1G -mtime +180 -type f -print`

Here's the explanation of the command option by option: Starting from the root directory, it finds all files bigger than 1 Gb, modified more than 180 days ago, that are of type "file", and prints their path.