# How to find files greater than a size in linux

Tags: linux, find, tree

I want to find user, size, modified date and full file path of all files in sub-directories starting from a dir. I have got to following so far:

```
nohup sudo \
tree /work/mydir \
-sufiD \
--noreport \
--timefmt="%Y-%m-%d" | \
sed -e 's/ \+/ /g' -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/\]//g' -e 's/\.\///g' -e 's/ /|/g' | \
tail -n+2 \
> usage_mydir.txt &
```

This gives me the desired output except that it lists **all** files; i want to filter out files say less than 10MB which will reduce my output file considerably (from over 500 MB to less than 5MB).

I am open to any other commands such as `find . -type f -size +10M`.
But I need the owner, size and last modified time of the file.

Comment: @Theophrastus, post that as an answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Files greater than 1 GB and older than 6 months](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203129/files-greater-than-1-gb-and-older-than-6-months)

Comment: 10 first hits on a Google search yields dupes and cross-dupes with accepted answers on SO, Super-User, unix.stackexchange and others.

Comment: @Cbhihe This is obviously not a duplicate of the question you linked as different output is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-ls` in find to get the owner size, and modification time:

`find . -type f -size +10M -ls`