# grep -v is not excluding the strings

Tags: grep, find, pipe

im trying to narrow down a flag to catch by removing strings with certain  unwanted words so  i use

```
cat $(find / -size 33c -group bandit6 -user bandit7) | grep -v 'Permission'
```

but my results end up being

```
find: ‘/cgroup2/csessions’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/bandit28-git’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/bandit30-git’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/bandit31-git’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/bandit5/inhere’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/bandit27-git’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/bandit29-git’: Permission denied
find: ‘/tmp’: Permission denied
find: ‘/lost+found’: Permission denied
find: ‘/root’: Permission denied
find: ‘/etc/ssl/private’: Permission denied
find: ‘/etc/lvm/backup’: Permission denied
find: ‘/etc/lvm/archive’: Permission denied
find: ‘/etc/polkit-1/localauthority’: Permission denied
find: ‘/sys/fs/pstore’: Permission denied
find: ‘/proc/tty/driver’: Permission denied
find: ‘/proc/24068/task/24068/fd/6’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/24068/task/24068/fdinfo/6’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/24068/fd/5’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/24068/fdinfo/5’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/boot/lost+found’: Permission denied
HKBPTKQnIay4Fw76bEy8PVxKEDQRKTzs
```

when all i want is

```
HKBPTKQnIay4Fw76bEy8PVxKEDQRKTzs
```

`

Comment: it does appear to be and issue with stderr but neither  `2>&1` or any use of `/dev/null` seem to resolve this

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42841/how-to-skip-permission-denied-errors-when-running-find-in-linux#comment58845_42842

Comment: yeh still  `2>/dev/null` has no affect

Comment: where'd you put it? It needs to relate to the `find` command: `find / -size 33c -group bandit6 -user bandit7 2>/dev/null`

Comment: solved it is because `2>/dev/null` was not inside `$(should be in here)`

Answer (score 0):

so it appears to `$()` was the problem

```
cat $(find / -size 33c -group bandit6 -user bandit7) 2>/dev/null
```

will not work, however

```
cat $(find / -size 33c -group bandit6 -user bandit7 2>/dev/null)
```

will work
i imagine `grep -v` may work with some mixture of stderr inside the brackets aswell

Comment: If you explain why the first command does not work and the second command does the job, your answer will get some upvotes.