# How to redirect the stderr to /dev/null and the stdout to the pipe in tcsh?

Tags: find, pipe, io-redirection, tcsh

I have the following code in `tcsh`:

```
set dirs = `find $path -follow -name "test" | grep -v ".data"`
```

It will find all the directories that have `test` directory under it, without including `.data`.

I noticed that if there is some problem while running `find`, for example, a broken link on the way, I'll get a "permissions denied" error and then the `tcsh` script is just hanging until I manually kill it. I'm trying to catch all the errors and redirect them to `/dev/null` and the output to redirect to `grep`.

I came across with different answer. For example, there was a [topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42842/417874) that suggested to ignore only "permission denied" - which worked, but I'm trying to redirect all the errors to `/dev/null` and not just one. But the problem is the pipe `|` - how can I redirect the stderr to `/dev/null` and the stdout to the pipe (which is `grep`)?

Comment: You should use another shell for those tasks. But if you want to use `tcsh` you can use this: `( find $path -follow -name "test" | grep -v ".data" > chsout.txt ) > & /dev/null`. You have to redirect the `stdout` to a file and read its content later (assign a variable it seems doesn't work. I'm not sure how should a variable be assigned.)