# How to use find to remove *.py~ and *.pyc files at once?

Tags: find

I want to cleanup a directory (and subdirectories) from each occurrance of the `.py` and `.pyc` files. I tried the following

```
find . -name '*pyc' -o -name '*py~' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

which left out all `pyc` files. When doing

```
find . -name '*pyc' -o -name '*py~'
```

the command finds the `pyc` files, which are not deleted, whatsoever. Any insights?

Answer (score 10):

The `-a` operator (implicit between two predicates) has precedence over `-o`, so you need parenthesis:

```
find . \( -name '*pyc' -o -name '*py~' \) -a -exec rm -f {} +
```

(I include the `-a` above for demonstration purpose only, it is not needed as it is implicit). I replaced `;` with `+` as there's probably no point running one `rm` per file if that can be avoided.

Comment: Why don't you just use -delete?

Comment: @Aif, because `-delete` is not a standard option. By all means, use it if your `find` supports it, but don't use it in scripts that are meant to be portable.

Comment: `find` is a lot like Perl. Amazingly powerful, but write-only.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Oh I didn't know! I have it under OSX on both find and gnu-find, so I though "if even BSD find has it, portable it must be!".

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using the `-o` why not just do a wildcard pattern?

```
find . -name '*py[c~]' -delete
```

or:

```
find . -name '*py[c~]' -exec rm -f {} +
```

Comment: Good point for this particular case. Note that it's not a regex, that's still a shell wildcard pattern.

Comment: Ahh, I always understood them to be the same. Thanks for correcting that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have bash 4+, you don't even need find, since globstar will give you recursive globbing:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**/*.py{c,~}; do rm "$f"; done
```

Note that `shopt` needs to be on its own line, rather than separated by a `;` (and should be used at the very top of a script, directly below the shebang if possible).

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question it's not so new...
but maybe it was enough to use

```
rm -f `find . -name '*.pyc' -o -name '*.py~' `
```