# How to find files ending with ~ and pyc?

Tags: find, wildcards, patterns

I want to find all files (in current and all subdirectory) which end in'~' or 'pyc'. To do so I have tried the following `find` pattern:

```
find . -name '*{~,pyc}'
find . -name '{*~,*.pyc}'
```

but neither list any of the files present in the diectory. Why do these patterns not work? How to do it right?

When using `ls` instead of `find` (without the quotation mark) I get the expected result (except that `ls` only shows the *current* directory and not all the subdirectories).

Comment: Why are you asking the [same question again](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71221/22565)?

Comment: It is a different question. I wanted to use a more compact expression to do a similar task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be much easier with regular expression if you have the GNU find,

`find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*(~|pyc)$'`

P.S I guess you're using shell expansion with find? If so, that's not possible, use `find . -name '*.pyc' -o -name '*~'` instead.

Answer (score 6):

```
find . -type f \( -name "*~" -o -name "*pyc" \)
```

This will return all files (`-type f`) that end with either `~` or (`-o`) `pyc`.

Answer (score 3):

If it's compactness you're after, with `zsh`:

```
printf '%s\n' **/*(~|pyc)(.D)
```

(`D` for dotfiles as well, `.` for regular files only)

If you wanted to use shell brace expansion, you'd have to do things like:

```
eval 'find . -type f ! \(' '! -name \*'{~,pyc} '\)'
```

Which the shell expands to:

```
eval 'find . -type f ! \(' '! -name \*~' '! -name \*pyc' '\)'
```

Which is then asking the shell to evaluate this command line:

```
find . -type f ! \( ! -name \*~ ! -name \*pyc \)
```