# Exclude paths that make find complain about permissions

Tags: permissions, find

I need to generate a file list from a disk volume. Some of the directories (all hidden directories under the root directory) have strange permissions that causes find to complain.

I try to exclude all these paths, but one directory still complains:

```
find . -type f -not -path './.*/*'
find: ./.DocumentRevisions-V100: Permission denied
```

The rights are like this (set so by the operating system, so I assume they shouldn't be messed with).

```
d--x--x--x root  wheel   .DocumentRevisions-V100
```

How do I change the `find` statement to effectively omit all the hidden directories as to not complain. (I do not want to do `2>/dev/null` as I want to know about other problems).

Comment: This set of permissions will prevent you from browsing the directory's contents (hence the `Permission denied` error) *but* it allows you to descend *through* the directory and access items within it if you already know the file or path name beneath it (and have the appropriate permissions there), so it can provide a useful layer of security.

Answer (score 7):

With GNU find or any other find that supports the `-readable` and `-executable` predicates:

```
find . -type d ! \( -readable -executable \) -prune -o -type f -not -path './.*/*' -print
```

First we prune directories that aren't traversable. If that condition doesn't apply, try the other condition(s).

If your `find` doesn't have these options, you can match against the file permissions.

```
find . -type d ! -perm -u+rx -prune -o -type f ! -path './.*/*' -print
```

Comment: I don't have GNU find. Your suggestion still gives "Permission denied", but -perm is probably the thing. How do I rearrange the statement to make it work?

Comment: @forthrin Oops, I had appended my conditions to yours which didn't make sense syntactically (resulting in `-type f … -type d` which matches nothing). Try now.

Comment: It works now! Perfect!

Comment: `-perm -u+rx` would check for directories whose owner (not necessarily you) has rx permission on.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of find is a strange beast indeed. I think you might have success with

```
find . -path './.*' -prune -o -type f -print
```

per the [find(1) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

> To ignore a whole directory tree, use -prune rather than checking every file in the tree. For example, to skip the directory 'src/emacs' and all files and directories under it, and print the names of the other files found, do something like this:

```
find . -path ./src/emacs -prune -o -print
```

Comment: Still complains about that one directory. Maybe because not even root have read permission?

Comment: I think you want `-path './.*'` (no trailing `/*`).

Answer (score 1):

```sh
u='-user "$USER"'
g='\('$(IFS=\ ;printf " -group %d " $(id -G))'\)'
eval "find / $u \( -perm -u=rx -o -prune \) -o \
             $g \( -perm -g=rx -o -prune \) -o \
                   -perm -o=rx -o -prune" | wc -l
```

That works. Because file permissions are always evaluated at the most specific level possible, you don't have to `-o`r *too* much. If a file is owned by someuser and is readable by others and groups but not by the owner then someuser still cannot read it. And so you just need to start at the most specific permission match and work your way down from there, `-pruning` all the while.

---

```
find: `/proc/3379/task/3379/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/3379/task/3379/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/3379/task/3379/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/3379/task/3379/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/3379/task/3379/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/3379/task/3379/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/3379/task/3379/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/3379/task/3379/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/3379/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/3379/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/3379/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/3379/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/3379/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/3379/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/3379/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/3379/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
327652
```

---

As you can see, at no point is there a permissions issue, just a few occasionally race issues to do with `/proc` - which is unavoidable when spawning files to read files.