# Why getting these "Permission Denied"s in POSIX find-grep readable?

Tags: grep, find, posix

I do in Posix `find $HOME +perm 0666 -type f -exec grep -l "XSym" {} \;` but get this which I do not understand

```
find: ‘/home/masi/.dbus’: Permission denied
grep: /home/masi/.viminfo: Permission denied
grep: /home/masi/.cache/dconf/user: Permission denied
```

since

```
drwx------  3 root root     4096 Jun 18 14:49 .dbus
-rw-------  1 root root     6266 Jun 18 13:24 .viminfo
-rw------- 1 root root 2 Jun 18 14:51 /home/masi/.cache/dconf/user
```

I do not like double negation structure and non-Posix things like `! -perm -g+r,u+r,o+r -prune` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25234419/54964) which I think is equivalent to `! -perm 0444 -prune`.

### Proposal after Kusalananda's fix

I do

```
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121020/16920
find / -type d \! -perm 0666 -prune -o -type f -name '._*' -print
```

Output: no files. Expected output: many files with many appropriate files. 
I run

```
find / -type d \! -perm +0666 -prune -o -type f -name '._*' -print
```

I get

```
find: invalid mode ‘+0666’
```

System: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Grep: 2.25
Find: 4.7.0-git

Comment: It's fine to prefer `0444` over `u+r,g+r,o+r` but in your command you didn't prune anything. There's no `-prune` in it. The pruning is what makes it skip the things you can't read. Also, `+perm` is definitely not right. It's always `-perm`. In some versions of find, `-perm +0666` would be a valid predicate (though maybe not the one you want)

Comment: Are you running the find as a nonroot user? They wouldn't have permission to read those ...

Comment: to clear some things up: `-perm +000` is deprected since 2005, that's why you get *invalid mode ‘+0666’*... use `-perm /000` instead.

Comment: and there are 3 different ways to search for permissions: `-perm 000` (only lists absolutely exact matches), `-perm -000` (list matches with at least all specified rights) and `-perm /000` (lists matches with also only matching one of the specified rights). perhaps that's why you get no files as output by using `-perm 0666`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those files and directories do not belong to you, they belong to the `root` user, and have too restrictive access permissions for `find` and `grep` to work. Therefore, `find` complains about not being able to enter the directory `/home/masi/.dbus` (to do its job), and `grep` complains about not being able to read the files (to do *its* job).

The files and directories do not belong to you, even though they are located in your home directory. The reason that they instead belong to the `root` user is likely that you have been running things (`vim` and other things) as `root` and whatever programs these were have created the files and directories.

You may change the ownership of these files and directories with `chown masi:masi` (`masi:masi` should be replaced with your username and your default group name, see your other files), but you need to be `root` to do it, so use `sudo chown ...`.

If you want to make sure that *all* files and directories in your home directory belongs to you, do `sudo chown -R masi:masi $HOME`, but first be sure that this is really what you want.

**EDIT**:
To find all files and directories in `$HOME` that *doesn't* belong to user `masi`, do this:

```
$ find $HOME \! -user masi
```

Comment: Well, did you run things as `root`?  In any case, these are not overly important files, and may even be deleted if you wish. Cache files are _always_ deletable, and I know for a fact that `.viminfo` only holds some state information from Vim, so that's deletable too. If I found a `.dbus` folder in my `$HOME`, I wouldn't care less if it was deleted.

Comment: Please, see the body. I am having the original problem again and again. I really have to understand this case. I give another proposal but no output at all of the command.

Comment: @Masi Try again with `-perm +0666`.

Comment: Please, see the body for the output. I get `invalid mode '+0666'`.

Comment: @Masi My answer was concerning why you get "permission denied" errors, because that was your question. I'm not sure what it is you want to do now.

Comment: I want to run the command successfully. The original may be right but something causing permission denied. I think the problem is not necessarily with the parameter value.